# Using @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE), the sequence_next_hi_value is an int(11) but my table have a id column bigint(20)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using @Id with @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE), just checked that hibernate have created a table hibernate_sequences, but the column type for the sequence_next_hi_value is an int(11). I have some entities (I mean tables) that have an id field of type bigint(20), will that works ? and when my table reach the number of rows I am expecting ?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> (...) hibernate has created a table hibernate_sequences, but the column type for the sequence_next_hi_value is an int(11). I have some entities (I mean tables) that have an id field of type bigint(20), will that works ?

Yest, this will work.

> and when my table reach the number of rows I am expecting?

I'm not sure I understood that part. But if the question is about running out of numbers, here are some numbers from the JPA wiki book:

> #### [Running Out of Numbers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Running_Out_of_Numbers)
>
> One paranoid delusional fear that
>   programmers frequently have is running
>   out of sequence numbers. Since most
>   sequence strategies just keep
>   incrementing a number it is
>   unavoidable that you will eventually
>   run out. However as long a large
>   enough numeric precision is used to
>   store the sequence id this is not an
>   issue. For example if you stored your
>   id in a NUMBER(5) column, this would
>   allow 99,999 different ids, which on
>   most systems would eventually run out.
>   **However if you store your id in a
>   NUMBER(10) column, which is more
>   typical, this would store
>   9,999,999,999 ids, or one id each
>   second for about 300 years** (longer
>   than most databases exist). But
>   perhaps your system will process a lot
>   of data, and (hopefully) be around a
>   very long time. If you store your id
>   in a NUMBER(20) this would be
>   99,999,999,999,999,999,999 ids, or one
>   id each millisecond for about
>   3,000,000,000 years, which is pretty
>   safe.
>
> But you also need to store this id in
>   Java. If you store the id in a Java
>   int, this would be a 32 bit number ,
>   which is 4,294,967,296 different ids,
>   or one id each second for about 200
>   years. If you instead use a long, this
>   would be a 64 bit number, which is
>   18,446,744,073,709,551,616 different
>   ids, or one id each millisecond for
>   about 600,000,000 years, which is
>   pretty safe.

IMO, an int(11) with a default allocation size of 50 gives you some time.

Comment: I love it when someone does the math on these things.